# How can these 2 loops be vectorized in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, vectorization, kalman-filter

I'm retrieving close to 400k values in `values`, which is pretty slow by itself (that code is not being shown), and then I try to do a prediction of those values through a Kalmann filter, the first loop is taking a little over a minute to run, and the second aroun 2 and half minutes, I think the first can be vectorized, but I'm not sure how, specially the `window_sma`. The second loop I'm not sure how I could deal with the i increasing the x array (`x = np.append(x, new_x_col, axis=1)`).

This is the first one, which tries to do a prediction based on the values from SMA, using polyfit and polyval:

```
window_sma = 200
sma_index = 500
offset = 50
SMA = talib.SMA(values, timeperiod = window_sma)
vector_X = [1, 2, 3, 15]
sma_predicted = []

start_time = time.time()
for i in range (sma_index, len(SMA)):
    j = int(i - offset)
    k = int(i - offset / 2)
    window_sma = [SMA[j], SMA[k], SMA[i]]
    polyfit = np.polyfit([1, 2, 3], window_sma, 2)
    y_hat = np.polyval(polyfit, vector_X)
    sma_predicted.append(y_hat[-1])
```

And the second one, which attemps to filter the output of the first for loop to have a better prediction of the values I got from SMA:

```
# Kalman Filter
km = KalmanFilter(dim_x = 2, dim_z = 1)

# state transition matrix
km.F = np.array([[1.,1.],
                [0.,1.]])
# Measurement function
km.H = np.array([[1.,0.]])

# Change in time
dt = 0.0001
a = 1.5

# Covariance Matrix
km.Q = np.power(a, 2) * \
       np.array([[np.power(dt,4)/4, np.power(dt,3)/2],
                 [np.power(dt,3)/2, np.power(dt,2)]])

# Variance
km.R = 1000

# Identity Matrix
I = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])

# Measurement Matrix
km.Z = np.array(sma_predicted)

# Initial state
x = np.zeros((2,1))
x = np.array([[sma_predicted[0]], [0]])

# Initial distribution state's covariance matrix
km.P = np.array([[1000, 0], [0, 1000]])

for i in range (0, len(sma_predicted) - 1):
    # Prediction
    new_x_col = np.dot(km.F, x[:, i]).reshape(2, 1)
    x = np.append(x, new_x_col, axis=1)
    km.P = km.F * km.P * km.F.T + km.Q

    # Correction
    K = np.dot(km.P, km.H.T) / (np.dot(np.dot(km.H, km.P), km.H.T) + km.R)
    x[:, -1] = x[:, -1] + np.dot(K, (km.Z[i + 1] - np.dot(km.H, x[:, -1])))
    #x[:, -1] = (x[:, -1] + K * (km.Z[i + 1] - km.H * x[:, -1])).reshape(2, i + 2)
    km.P = (I - K * km.H) * km.P
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The second one is worth attacking first, so I'll just do that.

You have this:

```
x = np.array([[sma_predicted[0]], [0]])
for i in range (0, len(sma_predicted) - 1):
    new_x_col = np.dot(km.F, x[:, i]).reshape(2, 1)
    x = np.append(x, new_x_col, axis=1)
    # ...
```

Repeatedly appending to the same array is always bad practice in NumPy, so start with something like this:

```
x = np.zeros((2, len(sma_predicted)))
x[0, 0] = sma_predicted[0]
for i in range(len(sma_predicted) - 1):
    x[:, i+1] = np.dot(km.F, x[:, i])
    # ...
```

Note the `reshape(2, 1)` is not needed, thanks to NumPy broadcasting.

I realize this does not answer all of your implicit questions, but perhaps it gets you started.

It would be nice if `dot` were a `ufunc` so we could do something like `np.dot.outer(km.F, x.T)`, but it isn't (see [this from 2009](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2009-December/047433.html)), so we can't.  You could implement more speedups using Numba (with the `append()` removed as I showed, your code is a good candidate for Numba).

Comment: Thanks, @JohnZwinck, if I do `x[:, i+1] = np.dot(km.F, x[:, i])`, I get problem with my final `x` value at the end of the loop, because it apaprently loses its (2,1) shape to become a (2,) shape. It does execute that loop waaaay faster, but with that problem it doesn't work for me. Is there something it can be done to solve that?

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, @JohnZwinck, I was forgotting to update the index used in `x` in the following lines. Now that loop runs in about 6 seconds. Thanks!